# Flash Builder 4 versus Flash CS5 event handling model

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, flash-builder, flash-cs5

What is the difference between the event handling paradigms between [Flash Builder 4](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67fe7-7ffe.html) and [Flash CS5](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fca.html) ? Flash is timeline based while Flex allows it to be in a XML file. [This page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6d20da321260fed8a52-8000.html) explains how to dispatch an event from the timeline, but in Flash Builder 4 there is no concept of timeline, hence what is the event model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event model for both is the same, events are fired and consumed. It's based on the [DOM event model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_handling_models) outlined by W3C, and essentially, an implementation of the [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) (GOF)

The timeline model is **entirely separate**, however, the Flash engine does fire EnterFrame events as the timeline/playhead advances. The EnterFrame event has been used from the early days of Flash to create dynamic (code based) animations.

Further Reading:

- [Understanding AS3 Event Flow](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/860/1/Understanding-the-AS3-Event-Flow/Page1.html)
- [Flex event listeners](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Event+Listeners)
- [Flex event dispatchers](http://www.flexafterdark.com/docs/ActionScript-EventDispatcher)

Comment: I might add that Flex is timeline based too, they've just done a lot of work to hide that from developers.  I think flex has 2 Frames, specifically.  One for the system set up and one for the code we write.

Comment: Well, that's getting away from the fact that Flex is just a framework for building FlashPlayer content.